# Ubuntu 20.04 VM always resizes screen to default size when booting

Tags: virtualbox, screen, display-resolution, 20.04

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 on virtualbox 6.0.20 and I have installed guest additions.

The issue is that if I resize the screen resolution to whatever size, even to predefined resolutions, it will always start/boot at 800x600 and I have to resize it again.

What I noticed is that when it boots, it goes for ~1 sec to the previous screen size but shows only black and then just before the wallpaper-desktop appears it goes to 800x600.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am having the same problem - losing of resolution of display setting everything I restart the image with Ubuntu 20.04 and Virtual box - Version 6.1.14 r140239 (Qt5.6.2). When I tried the VMSVGA driver the ubuntu guest system stops responding to mouse click and I could not type anything. System becomes very slow. I have not tried older version of Virtual Box that is my next step

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem with the new Kubuntu release. Do the following:

1. Shut down your Ubuntu VM.
2. Open the Settings for your Ubuntu VM and select the **Display** section
3. Select **VBoxSVGA** as your Graphics Controller. VirtualBox will warn you at the bottom of the Settings window about the invalid settings, you can ignore that.
4. Leave the option **Enable 3D Acceleration** unchecked, otherwise VirtualBox will revert the Graphics Controller back to VMSVGA when you confirm the settings.
5. Confirm your choices by clicking **OK**.
6. Start your Ubuntu VM.

I'm using VM VirtualBox ver. 6.1.6, Extension Pack (with included Guest additions virtual CD) is also 6.1.6

If someone knows how how to remedy the resolution issue with **VMSVGA** selected as Graphics Controller, I'd love to read it.

*Update #1*
This issue with screen resizing didn't let go of me, so I went and searched on the web some more.

From what I've read - and with my limited knowledge of inner workings of Linux systems, hopefully understood it at least somewhat correctly - the problem lies in relation between the graphic drivers included in Oracle's VM VirtualBox Guest Additions and the new Linux kernels that came with the recently released version of Ubuntu distro and others based on it. It seems the drivers present in ver. 6.1.6 Guest Additions aren't working correctly with these new kernels, hence the resizing problem when the Graphics Controller in VM is set to VMSVGA.

So until Oracle comes up with updated version of VirtualBox/Guest Additions, the temporary solution is the one I explained above, or what I've tried earlier and for me at least, works as well.

1. Uninstall the current Guest Additions from your VM, then power it off.
2. Download the older version - 6.1.2 ISO ([link to Oracle's web page](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.2/), there's only one such file listed).
3. Start your VM and after you logged back, open VM **Devices** menu, select **Optical Drives** > **Choose a disc file...** to mount Guest Additions CD.
4. Open your terminal and run the install script **VBoxLinuxAdditions.run** located in the root of the CD.
5. Follow this step if your VM Graphics Controller is set to VBoxSVGA, otherwise skip to step 6: Power off the VM and in Settings > Display > Graphics Controller select **VMSVGA**, also enable **3D Acceleration**. Confirm changes by clicking **OK**.
6. Restart the VM, automatic screen resizing should work now.

I chose version 6.1.2 of Guest Additions because there's a bug with Bidirectional Clipboard support in 6.1.4.

Comment: I just had a similar problem with 6.1.6. Your steps described above did not help in my case. Installing the Guest Additions 6.1.2 alone didn't do it but switching View -> "Auto-resize Guest Display" off and then on again afterwards did the trick for me.
Who knows, maybe only toggling that option works right out of the box.

Comment: @linkD Thank you for the feedback on this. I've never tried to toggle that option. I'll give it a go with 6.1.6 Guest Additions installed.

Comment: I am using Guest Addition 6.1.8 and facing this issue. I toggled the "Auto-resize Guest Display" option and it did not help.

Comment: which version of the guest additions do i need to use on Focal Fossa? I see eoan.. But no focal.. I'm having the same issue. i'm hesitating to upgrade my Eoan because of this issue..

Comment: Thanks, I selected `VBoxSVGA` and it works now. Would like to follow up and ask if there are any downside of using `VBoxSVGA` instead of `VMSVGA`, is there any benefit of using `VMSCVGA` instead of `VBoxSVGA`? Thanks.

Comment: Facing the same issue on 6.1.24. Switching to VBoxSVGA helped, thank you!

Comment: I am on VirtualBox 6.38, with Guest Additions properly installed by the Vagrant plugin.
Used VBoxSVGA as described and seems the resolution is correct judging by the white Ubuntu logo on a black background displayed when the machine starts to boot, but then all I see is a blinking cursor in the top left corner of the screen and the VM never gets to the login screen. The VirtualBox GUI shows the VM as running, though.

Comment: +1 The solution didn't work for me, but switching to VMSVGA, seeing that it made things even worse, (I've got my VM sprawled along 3 monitors which might be a factor) then switching back seemed to work, so indirectly, your answer worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. [Upgrade to 6.1.8](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), and the problem goes away.

Comment: I'm using 6.1.8 and I still have the problem.

Comment: @user118967 did you also install the new version of VirtualBox Guest Additions?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 6.1.8 which is the latest version of both VirtualBox and Guest Additions.

Comment: Just to make sure, you have to also install the Guest Additions into your guest OS. From the guest OS, did you re-mount the Guest Additions ISO and re-install on that OS?

Comment: Yes, I did that. I am guessing the bug remains in the latest version, but does not always manifest in all systems?

Comment: @user118967 that's possible. My Ubuntu 20.04 is pretty vanilla.

Comment: Still broken in exactly the manner described here, using Ubuntu 20 LTS under VirtuaBox 6.1.22 with its Guest Additions installed.