# Ubuntu 20.04 under VirtualBox does not Auto-resize Guest Display

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, kubuntu, display-resolution, resize

I had a problem when installed Ubuntu 20.04 as a guest in VirtualBox 6.1.18
The Auto-resize Guest Display did not work and I was able only to set one of the pre-defined resolutions in the Ubuntu.
The question is how to enable the Auto-resize?

Answer (score 4):

I found a good answer here: https://kifarunix.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-ubuntu-20-04/

1. If Guest Additions ISO is already installed, eject it: Start File manager -> find in the left panel “Vbox_Gas_6.1.18” -> press Eject button
2. Install required build tools:

sudo apt update -y

sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential

3. Reboot Ubuntu
4. Start Ubuntu -> Insert the Guest Additions ISO: Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD image
5. Reboot Ubuntu

This is to contribute to this discussion:
[Ubuntu 20.04 VM always resizes screen to default size when booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230797/ubuntu-20-04-vm-always-resizes-screen-to-default-size-when-booting)